# Showing circle on the map displays elongated ellipse instead

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, spatial, gmap.net

I need to display a circle around a point on the map. I'm working with the windows app and GMap.NET control. Instead of a circle, I'm getting this:

[image]

Here is a sql I'm using to get polygon points:

```
declare @lat float = 43.722385, @lng float = -79.415241, @radius int = 100;
DECLARE @g geography;
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + Str(@lat, 10, 7) + ' ' + Str(@lng, 10, 7) + ')', 4326);
SELECT @g.STBuffer(@radius).STAsText() as circle, @g.STBuffer(@radius)
```

I seem to be getting correct results:

[image]
But when displayed on the map, I'm getting an ellipse as you can see on the first image.

Here is the example of the boundaries of the polygon, if I just find max/min values of all the lats and lngs and show them in bing maps just as sanity check and to confirm that this is not just a GMap.NET issue:

[image]

Here is the code I'm using to create a circle using polygon:

```
 List<PointLatLng> points = new List<PointLatLng>();
 string[] ps = radCirclePoints.Split(',');
 foreach (string p in ps) {
     string[] coords = p.Trim().Split(' ');
     points.Add(new PointLatLng(double.Parse(coords[0]), double.Parse(coords[1])));
 }

 GMapPolygon polygon = new GMapPolygon(points, "circ");
 polygon.Fill = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Red));
 polygon.Stroke = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);
 markersOverlay.Polygons.Add(polygon);
```

What is going on here? using STBuffer is such an elegant way to find boundaries for polygon to display a circle, but it is failing somewhere. Any ideas?

Comment: i am seeing ellipse in ssms instead of circle, when running your query.

Comment: Not the same kind of ellipse though, I bet. If you change projection to Mercator, you would see a circle.

Comment: Tilt your monitor forward/backward until it looks like a circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating the STGeomFromText you have the lat and long reversed. Once you change this order then you will also have to adjust the order you are parsing them from the buffer output. By having them reversed the point is being buffered as if it is at/below the south pole and that is why the ellipse.

```
DECLARE @g geography;
SET @g = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + Str(@lng, 10, 7) + ' ' + Str(@lat, 10, 7) + ')', 4326);

SELECT @g.STBuffer(@radius).STAsText() as circle, @g.STAsText() AS point, @g.STBuffer(@radius)
```

then in the c#

```
List<PointLatLng> points = new List<PointLatLng>();
 string[] ps = radCirclePoints.Split(',');
 foreach (string p in ps) {
     string[] coords = p.Trim().Split(' ');
     points.Add(new PointLatLng(double.Parse(coords[1]), double.Parse(coords[0])));
 }
```